# how to display multiple markers simultaneously using the Pnp Map control

Tags: spfx, pnp-js, sharepointframework

I want to display several markers simultaneously on a Map in SPFX WebPart. Is there a way to do this using the  [Pnp Map Control](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/Map/).